# Cómo calcular el máximo de una función cuadrática?

Tags: c++, matemáticas, ecuacion-cuadratica

Necesito calcular el valor máximo de esta función:

```
F(x) = -2x^2 + 200x
```

Para ello, he realizado lo siguiente:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

main()
{
    int maximo,i;

    for ( i >= 2; true; i++)
    {
       maximo = -2 * i + 200 * i;
       cout << " El valor máximo de la función es " << maximo << endl;
       break;
    }   
}
```

He sacado el vértice máximo y es (x, y) (50, 5000), la fórmula para obtener los vértices es:

```
(-b/2a, 4ac-b^2/4a)
```

Comment: Hola Diego me puedes decir si la respuesta dada te fue útil o si necesitas más ayuda, gracias

Comment: Hola, me sirvió la respuesta, mil gracias!!!

Comment: Diego si la respuesta te sirvio te agradeceria que le dieras un voto y la marcaras como aceptada, gracias

Comment: [Teorema de Fermat](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teorema_de_Fermat_(an%C3%A1lisis)): Si una función f alcanza un máximo o mínimo local en c, y si la derivada f '(c) existe en el punto c, entonces f '(c) = 0. Es decir, deberías revisar los puntos donde la derivada de la función es 0. Y si la segunda derivada te da negativo se trata de un máximo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La **forma general de una función cuadrática** es:

```
ax ^ 2 + bx + c
```

Las funciones cuadráticas tienen forma de parábola y pueden estar orientadas hacia arriba o hacia abajo.

Si **a** es positiva la parábola está orientada hacia arriba(una **U**), y si **a** es negativa la parábola está orientada hacia abajo(**U** invertida).

En tu ejemplo:

```
a = -2
b = 200
c = 0
```

Como ves el valor de **a** es negativo por tanto la parábola está orientada hacia abajo, y para hallar su **valor máximo** hacemos lo siguiente, atendiendo a los valores de tu ejemplo:

```
int a = -2;
int b = 200;
int c = 0;

float x = -b / (2 * a);
```

Aquí declaramos tres variables enteras **a**, **b**, **c** con sus respectivos valores, y posteriormente guardamos en la variable **x** el valor x del vértice de la parábola.

Posteriormente hallamos el valor de **f(x)** o lo que es lo mismo que hallar el valor de **y**:

```
float y = (-2 * x * x) + 200 * x;
```

Y este valor obtenido en la **variable** **y** será el **valor máximo** de la función, este es el valor que debes imprimir.

Answer (score 0):

Tu pregunta no está muy clara respecto a si la entrada es fija o no
pero entiendo que sí.

```
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    // Obteniendo la derivada de la función -2x^2 + 200x
    // F'(x) = -4x + 200
    // el valor máximo en x es cuando la derivada == 0
    // 0 = -4x + 200; -> x = 50;
    // obteniendo el valor de x en F -> F(50) = 5000

    // ahora bien si quieres ocupar la formula que se te ha dado: 

    float a = -2.0;
    float b = 200.0;
    float c = 0;
    float x_coord = -b / (2*a);
    float y_coord = 4 * a*c - (b*b) / (4 * a);

    std::cout <<"Max_Value: " <<"(" << x_coord <<", " << y_coord << ")" <<std::endl;


}
```